# Flutter: Zoom map to a different value when location permissions are denied

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation

I am currently updating a existing app, in the app I have Google Map with markers on it, the markers are pulled from Firebase.

Everything is working but I have one question that I can't get working. I ask the users permission and when it is granted everything works fine, the location gets pulled and the map get's updated (camera position and zoom).

When the user denies permission the same happens but I want the Google Map to be a little zoomed out because I don't know the location of the user (so more of a overview).

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:hvd/styling/colors.dart';
import 'package:hvd/helpers/navigation.dart';
import 'package:hvd/helpers/markers.dart';

// This page shows a Google Map plugin with all stations (HvD and Total). The markers are pulled from a Firebase database.

Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the
    // App to enable the location services.
    return Position(
        latitude: 51.9045,
        longitude: 5.4298,
        timestamp: DateTime.now(),
        accuracy: 0.0,
        altitude: 0.0,
        heading: 0.0,
        speed: 0.0,
        speedAccuracy: 0.0);
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
      return Position(
          latitude: 51.9045,
          longitude: 5.4298,
          timestamp: DateTime.now(),
          accuracy: 0.0,
          altitude: 0.0,
          heading: 0.0,
          speed: 0.0,
          speedAccuracy: 0.0);
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      return Position(
        latitude: 51.9045,
        longitude: 5.4298,
        timestamp: DateTime.now(),
        accuracy: 0.0,
        altitude: 0.0,
        heading: 0.0,
        speed: 0.0,
        speedAccuracy: 0.0,
      );
    }
  }

  // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
  // continue accessing the position of the device.
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}

class StationsMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const StationsMap({super.key});

  @override
  StationsMapState createState() => StationsMapState();
}

class StationsMapState extends State<StationsMap> {
  bool _isLocationGranted = false;

  dynamic currentLocation;

  late GoogleMapController mapController;

  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};

// Below function initiates all HvD stations and shows them as markers on the map. It also generates a Bottom Sheet for each location with corresponding information.

  void initMarkerHvD(specify, specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final Uint8List markerHvD =
        await getBytesFromAsset('images/Pin-HvD.JPG', 100);
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: Container(
                      color: const Color(0xff757575),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(20.0))),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              specify['stationName'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: PaletteBlue.hvdblue,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 16),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(specify['stationAddress']),
                            Text(specify['stationZIP'] +
                                ' ' +
                                specify['stationCity']),
                            const SizedBox(height: 20),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        PaletteOrange.hvdorange)),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  MapUtils.openMap(
                                      specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
                                      specify['stationLocation'].longitude);
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Navigeer naar locatie',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
      },
      position: LatLng(specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
          specify['stationLocation'].longitude),
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerHvD),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

// Below function initiates all Total stations and shows them as markers on the map. It also generates a Bottom Sheet for each location with corresponding information.

  void initMarkerTotal(specify, specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final Uint8List markerTotal =
        await getBytesFromAsset('images/Pin-Total.JPG', 100);
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: Container(
                      color: const Color(0xff757575),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(20.0))),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              specify['stationName'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: PaletteBlue.hvdblue,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 16),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(specify['stationAddress']),
                            Text(specify['stationZIP'] +
                                ' ' +
                                specify['stationCity']),
                            const SizedBox(height: 20),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        PaletteOrange.hvdorange)),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  MapUtils.openMap(
                                      specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
                                      specify['stationLocation'].longitude);
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Navigeer naar locatie',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
      },
      position: LatLng(specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
          specify['stationLocation'].longitude),
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerTotal),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

// Below function initiates all Fieten stations and shows them as markers on the map. It also generates a Bottom Sheet for each location with corresponding information.

  void initMarkerFieten(specify, specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final Uint8List markerFieten =
        await getBytesFromAsset('images/Pin-Fieten.JPG', 100);
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      onTap: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    child: Container(
                      color: const Color(0xff757575),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
                                topRight: Radius.circular(20.0))),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              specify['stationName'],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: PaletteBlue.hvdblue,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 16),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            Text(specify['stationAddress']),
                            Text(specify['stationZIP'] +
                                ' ' +
                                specify['stationCity']),
                            const SizedBox(height: 20),
                            ElevatedButton(
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        PaletteOrange.hvdorange)),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  MapUtils.openMap(
                                      specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
                                      specify['stationLocation'].longitude);
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Navigeer naar locatie',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ));
      },
      position: LatLng(specify['stationLocation'].latitude,
          specify['stationLocation'].longitude),
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow(),
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerFieten),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

// Below functions pulls all HvD markers from the database.

  getMarkerDataHvD() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('hvd-stations')
        .get()
        .then((myMarkers) {
      if (myMarkers.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMarkers.docs.length; i++) {
          initMarkerHvD(myMarkers.docs[i].data(), myMarkers.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

// Below function pulls all Total markers from the database.

  getMarkerDataTotal() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('total-stations')
        .get()
        .then((myMarkers) {
      if (myMarkers.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMarkers.docs.length; i++) {
          initMarkerTotal(myMarkers.docs[i].data(), myMarkers.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

// Below function pulls all Fieten markers from the database.

  getMarkerDataFieten() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('fieten-stations')
        .get()
        .then((myMarkers) {
      if (myMarkers.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myMarkers.docs.length; i++) {
          initMarkerFieten(myMarkers.docs[i].data(), myMarkers.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

// Below function initiates all previous functions on the page. This happens when the user navigates to the page.

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Call _determinePosition to get the user's current position
    _determinePosition().then((position) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = position;
        _isLocationGranted = true;
      });

      // After getting the position, update the camera position of the map
      mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(
          LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude), 14));
    });

    // Initialize markers from the Firestore database
    getMarkerDataHvD();
    getMarkerDataTotal();
    getMarkerDataFieten();
  }

  final CameraPosition _initialCameraPosition =
      const CameraPosition(target: LatLng(51.9045, 5.4298), zoom: 8);

// Below function is used to display all previous functions to the page.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
              gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
                Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                ),
              },
              mapToolbarEnabled: false,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: _isLocationGranted,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }
}
```

Can someone please put me in the right direction?

Comment: Anyone? I am really stuck right now!